# React Bootstrap Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me how to add telephone number to the react bootstrap buttons, when clicking should call that number.
I have used div tags and link to make it look like a button. what I want to do is to make the button work the in the same way as anchor tag

code :

```
         <div className='phone-no'>
            <Link className='link-phone-no' to='tel:+12-345-678-89089'>
              +12-345-678-89089
            </Link>
          </div>
```

Comment: add your code, what you are currently trying

Answer (score 1):

As I can see that `import {Button} from 'bootstrap_path';` And then use it having path binded with an onclick event listener that will call the function.
You may use useref hook to get the desired values with it.

```
<Button onclick={function_name} ref={myref}>some text{number}</Button>
```

Comment: This is nothing but simple button when clicking should try to contact that number. Why do we need to be so complicated for this simple thing?  But thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Adding Link to Button with phone number]

This method can make the button acts as a link component with clicking can go to a contact no we entered. The first set of button code is for mui v5 and second set of code is for react-bootstrap

import these components first:

```
    import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { Button } from '@mui/material';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"; --- index.js file
before calling App component add BrowserRouter component

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

```
mui:
```

```
    <Button
     component={Link}
     to="tel:+91-97875-97431"
     variant="contained"
     size="medium"
    >
    +91-97875-97431
    </Button>
```

```
react-bootstrap:
```

```
    

    <Button
        as={Link}
        to="tel:+91-97875-97431"
        variant="contained"
        color="success"
        size="large"
        >
        +91-97875-97431
        </Button>
```

Comment: Please include code not as images as to help other users to more quickly copy/paste/edit your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).